# svn merge --reintegrate gets stuck

Tags: svn

I am running svn client 1.7 and server 1.8. I have a branch. I have merged the trunk into branch about once every few days. Now i'm ready to reintegrate to the trunk. I run

```
svn merge --reintegrate https://path/to/branch/ .
```

Everything goes fine at first. Things start merging. After a hundred or so files, it just stops. The svn client doesn't quit. It just stops doing anything. I wait and wait and wait... nothing.

What's going on? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the client upgraded and it seems to have fixes the issue